# Parametrizing spherical representations by semisimple conjugacy classes

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, automorphic-forms

Let $p$ be a finite place (a prime) and $\pi$ an irreducible representation of $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ that is unramified, i.e. has nonzero fixed vectors by the maximal compact subgroup.

It is often used (to define L-functions for instance) that then $\pi$ corresponds to a semisimple conjugacy class in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. In which way is that so?

And how, conversely, does one associate a representation to such a conjugacy class?

Comment: Have you read volume II of Goldfeld-Hundley? I think it is explained there. Basically, if $\pi$ is a generic irreducible admissible smooth representation that is unramified, then it is a spherical principal series representation associated to the minimal parabolic subgroup, and the data describing this representation is the same as the data describing a semisimple conjugacy class.

Comment: @PeterHumphries Thanks, I will check it.